# Rails 4: Changing devise routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `Devise 3.4.1` and I have a model who belongs_to devise's `User`( Called `resume`. Instead of having `localhost:3000/resume/new`I want to change it to do `localhost:3000/users/resume/new`. I tried the following:

```
namespace :users do
    resources :resume, except: [:index]
  end
```

But it shows :

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /user/resume/new
uninitialized constant User::ResumeController
```

The controller is the code below:

```
class ResumeController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_resume, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @resumes = Resume.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @resume = current_user.resumes.build
    end

    def create
        @resume = current_user.resumes.build(resume_params)

        if @resume.save
            redirect_to @resume, notice: "resume was successfully created"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @resume.update(resume_params)
            redirect_to @resume, notice: "resume was successfully updated"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @resume.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def resume_params
        params.require(:resume).permit(:description, :skills, 
                                        jobs_attributes: [:id, :company_name, :location, :title, :duration, :description, :_destroy], 
                                        educations_attributes: [:id, :establishment, :Location, :majored, :duration, :description, :_destroy] )
    end

    def find_resume
        @resume = resume.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**

After adding a "s" in User (routes.rb) I'm getting the same error: here are my routes:

[image]

Comment: it's throwing error at `/user/resume/new` and you want `/users/resume/new`, seems like missing an `s` there. show us your `rake routes`

Comment: the problem aside, what's the relationship between users and resumes? one to one or one to many? Your resume controller is in singular, but it seems like you have a one to many relationship between users and resumes, then the controller name should be `ResumesController`

Comment: Actually i want the user to have *one* resume. So Instead of using `Has_many` in user.model I use `Has_one` ?

Comment: yea, also change this `@resume = current_user.resumes.build` to `@resume = current_user.resume.build`

Comment: Ok, I did all the changes. For the routes I changed `namespace :users do
    resources :resume, except: [:index]
  end` for `devise_scope :user do
   resources :resume, except: [:index]
  end `but I'm having this error: `NoMethodError at /resume/new
undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: it's saying whatever you call `build` on is `nil`, go to `rails console` to try it out first to see if it's working. `User.first.resume` to see if it returns nil

Comment: Yes, it returns Nil, but i'm unable to go to resume/new...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'resume/new' => 'resumes#new', as: 'new_resume'
end
```

Comment: It gives me an error: `No route matches [GET] "/users/resume/new"`

Comment: That's because the path is `/user/resume/new` not `/users/resume/new`